# Highcharts ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I'm finding the highcharts a mind field to get working outside of the demo examples. When looking at stackoverflow there are tonnes of examples done in so many different ways for many different situations.

I've tried to take bits and pieces of the code to get it working but to no avail.

I am trying to load a chart to reload and update the chart every few seconds. I got the ajax call to work, the data to feed through and called every few seconds. But I can't figure out a way for highcharts to take the data and build the chart.

This is the data sent back from ajax, which is a Multi Series result

```
[{"name":"One","data":[[1433203200000,0],[1433289600000,0],[1433376000000,0],[1433462400000,0],[1433548800000
,0],[1433635200000,31.48],[1433721600000,0]]},{"name":"Two","data":[[1433203200000,0],[1433289600000
,0],[1433376000000,0],[1433462400000,0],[1433548800000,0],[1433635200000,0],[1433721600000,0]]}]
```

This is the highchart code, what am I doing wrong?

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'final',
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        events: {
            load: function()
            {
              setTimeout(function(){
                 $.ajax({
                    url: 'test',
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                      console.log(data);
                      chart.setData(data,true);
                        //chart.setData(data,true);
                    }
                  });
              }, 10000);                  
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150,
        maxZoom: 20 * 1000
    },
    yAxis: {
        minPadding: 0.2,
        maxPadding: 0.2,
        title: {
            text: 'Value',
            margin: 80
        }
    },
    series: []
});
```

Comment: post your php or serverside code

Comment: Hi Hanoncs is the serverside code important as the original is huge doing alot of calculations which are irrelevant to the question. The output is what it is as listed above, I'm trying to get that output into Highcharts

Comment: Yes it is important, you need to return the data using json_encode

Comment: Just an fyi...On stackoverflow, you arrow up things that you like or help you and if it answers your question, you check the check mark.

Comment: ok cool, still looking for an answer though. I still don't know how to get multi series into building a chart. I'll have to do more digging around

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) `setTimeout` is called only once. You probably want to use `setInterval`.

2) There's no such method like `chart.setData()`. There is [`series.setData()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData). Open demo and check out how it's used. In your case callback should look that way:

```
        load: function() {
          var myChart = this;
          setInterval(function() {
             $.ajax({
                url: 'test',
                type: 'GET',
                async: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                  $.each(data, function(i, d) {
                      if(myChart.series[i]) {
                          myChart.series[i].setData(d.data,false, false);
                      } else { // series doesn't exist
                          myChart.addSeries(d, false);
                      }
                  });
                  myChart.redraw(true);
                }
              });
          }, 1000);                  
        }
```

Comment: This looks quite close, looks like you are setting the series individually. In your example what if there were now 4 series sent back from DB. Do you have to manually set them as series 2 and 3. I'm guessing now you could do some form of a loop?

Comment: Yes, you can use `for()` to loop over all series. I just noticed one thing, your `series` array is empty one. There should be some series defined to use `setData()`. Or when series doesn't exist use `addSeries()`. See updated answer.